# Trying to get file name and folder name with space

Tags: linux, shell, dirname, basename

I'm trying to get my folder name and file name (without extension, but i figure out doing without extension). 
if I can get in array that will be great but I'm still working on space problem.
its getting only parent folder name and file name including space in folder name.

For Example)

```
bin/data/ex/1.json
bin/data/2.json
bin/data fix/3.json (there is a space between data and fix, 'data fix')
bin/4.json
```

Result)

```
ex_1
data_2
data fix_3 or datafix_3 (with space or no space is fine)
bin_4
```

actually my data)

```
./123, 1/2.json
./ex/1.json
```

wanted result)

```
 123, 1_2 or 123,1_2
 ex_1
```

Here is my codes

```
for i in $(find . -iname "*.json")
#find *.json under folder and current folder
do
        echo "i(.json) is $i"
# TEst Print  .json file 
        dr="$(basename "$(dirname "$i")")"
        echo "dr is $dr"
# Test pring $dr
        name=$(sudo basename $i .json);
# Test print file name
        echo "name is $name"

        echo "foldername_filename is $dr _$name"
        echo "foldername_filename2 is $(basename "$(dirname "$i")")_$(basename $i .json)"
done
```

but I got

```
i(.json) is ./123,
dr is .
name is 123,
foldername_filename is . _123,
foldername_filename2 is ._123,
i(json) is 1/2.json
dr is 1
name is 2
foldername_filename is 1 _2
foldername_filename2 is 1_2
i(json) is ./ex/1.json
dr is ex
name is 1
foldername_filename is ex _1
foldername_filename2 is ex_1
```

Comment: You basically can't do this because `for i in $(cmd)` uses spaces as the seperator. You will have better luck either using `find` with its own --exec feature, or piped to `xargs`, which expects newlines. If you really want to keep the code "inline" then you could use a `find | while read` construction. Google will find you some good examples.